# Grub 2, switch os when restarting

Tags: grub2

I dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu. Usually, when I restart my computer, it is to switch os. Is there a way to tell it to Grub so that it preselects the right os in its menu when I restart my computer?

Currently, I have the following two lines in /etc/default/grub file :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

These lines make Grub preselects the os I just left. Maybe there is a similar way to tell Grub that I want it to preselect the os I use *before* the one I just left.